# Copying a complex data structure

Tags: database, postgresql

In our Postgres database, we have a structure of

class 1-* assignments 1-* questions 1-* alternatives

Previously assignments could be reused for multiple classes, meaning that several classes could point to the same assignment id and all was fine with the world.

Now, we need to make a change in the system that requires that assignments are unique for each class. This means we need to replicate the assignments into several copies so we can make them unique to each class.

So, we would generate unique assignments for each class and each of them would have their own questions and alternatives.

What's the most efficient way to replicate this without having to build a huge recursive code?

Comment: [homework] ? Tip: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`

Comment: That wouldn't solve the recursive issue.

Comment: What recursion? I only see the need for some joins, going by the description. No sample data and table definitions or expected results so I can't really test.